# Ext.device.Connection.isOnline() is not working in iOS

Tags: extjs, connectivity

I have an iOS sencha application which needs to check the internet connection. I am using the code if (Ext.device.Connection.isOnline()) 
      {
        alert('Connectivity is available .');
    } else {
        alert('No Network Connectivity.');
            } 
The above code is working fine with Chrome and safari browsers, but its not working through iOS app. I am using cordova 3.5.0-0.2.6, sencha touch 2.3.1 and Sencha Cmd 5.0.0.160 version

Tested in iPhone with iOS 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Ext alert instead:

```
if (Ext.device.Connection.isOnline()) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('OK', 'Connectivity is available');
} else Ext.Msg.alert('ERROR', 'No Network Connectivity');
```

Comment: Ext.device.Connection.isOnline() is also not working. Instead of it I used  " navigator.onLine " but this not perfect always taking time to detect connectivity status.

Comment: Ext.device.Connection.isOnline() has never failed to me. You should report this issue in sencha forums.